# Running Pumba in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Currently I am trying to install Pumba (https://github.com/gaia-adm/pumba) into my Minishift 1.7.0 cluster. After enabling developer user as cluster-admin and allowing volumes to use hostPath with /var/run/docker.sock I was able to deploy the pumba pod. The problem is that when pumba tries to connect to current docker socket there is an exception:

time="2017-10-19T13:42:30Z" level=debug msg="Retrieving running containers" 
time="2017-10-19T13:42:30Z" level=error msg="Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/containers/json?limit=0: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"

It seems there is some permissions problem that I have tried to fix without much success.

I have created a gist so you can see how Docker image of Pumba is created as well as the kubernetes file: https://gist.github.com/lordofthejars/14b6999395fb3986694c05bf48453d08

Probably it is something really simple to fix, but I cannot find a way.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: "After enabling developer user as cluster-admin" how you did that?

Comment: It looks like a pod was running under non-privileged user. Could you check it? Also, please, check which by SCC a pod was admitted (`oc get pod <pod> -o yaml` and look on annotations).

Comment: My current theory is that you have to grant access to `anyuid` SCC to a `default` service account of the current namespace. See here for more information: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#enable-dockerhub-images-that-require-root

Comment: I added cluster-admin role using `oc adm policy  --as system:admin add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin developer`

Comment: Because you're using a `DaemonSet`, a pod is being created on behalf of the service account `default` not on behalf of a user who is trying to create a pod. It happens because `DaemonSet` is being created and manager by a controller that is running under a service account. Try to grant access to `anyuid` SCC to `default` service (in the current namespace).

Comment: I have run `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid default` and then I deploy the resources again but I got the same problem.

Comment: Yes, because you granted access to user `default` but instead you should grant it to the service account. Service accounts have names like `system:serviceaccount:<project>:<name>`. Because I don't know the name of the project, I couldn't give you exact command. Another option is to use `-z` flag. See examples in the docs: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#add-scc-to-user-group-project

Comment: project is called fasttest. Now with `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid system:serviceaccount:fasttest:default` exactly the same result

Comment: Which SCC admitted a pod? Need an output of `oc get pod <pod> -o yaml | grep scc`

Comment: `openshift.io/scc: restricted`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lordofthejars/ddcea3cffc79968360c60930dc64afe3

Comment: Could you also modify a pod specification and add `runAsUser: 0` to its `securityContext`?

Comment: Error creating: pods "pumba-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: [securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 0: UID on container pumba does not match required range. Found 0, required min: 1000060000 max: 1000069999]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged system:serviceaccount:fasttest:default` with `privileged` instead of `anyuid`